# Group mysql results by day and echo to php page with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'll do my best to explain:

I am retrieving records from a mysql database to be outputted to a php page.

The results need to be grouped by day and also have pagination.

Example:

**August 24th**

- Result 1 (e.g. title, description, picture)
- Result 2 (e.g. title, description, picture)
- Result 3 (e.g. title, description, picture)

**August 23th**

- Result 1 (e.g. title, description, picture)
- Result 2 (e.g. title, description, picture)
- Result 3 (e.g. title, description, picture)

**Pagination:**  [1][2][3][4]

The above example is for illustrative purpose only as there will be **4 days** worth of results on each page. I am aware that each page, after the initial page, will need to be offset by 4 days by posting a parameter to the page.

However I can't figure out the logic to display the results by day.

I know a while or foreach loop is needed and possibly a loop within a loop to get all the results for each day.

I have been searching the net for a while now and can't seem to find any examples or guidance on how to do so.

I don't want the code spoon fed to me, just the logic of how to approach this scenario.

If anyone can help I would be most grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your table structure please? Create table sql query or something that helps us understand your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

After the simple database queries (which, remember, you need to LIMIT - literally - to allow for pagination), you can break off the array into days by check whether it's a new day during each loop.

```
$lastday = null;
while($entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($lastday != $entry['day']) {
        $lastday = $entry['day'];
        echo '<h3>' . $lastday . '</h3>';
    }
    // echo the entry result (title, description, picture)
}
```

You might want to adjust the lastday and entry['day'] parameters to reflect whatever date format you use (be it mysql, unix, or strings). Also, I used level 3 headings as an example, but you should choose whatever fits logically in your context.

Comment: Oh, sorry about spoon feeding you the code, but that's just the most logical way of explaining the concept.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I now have the page displaying as desired. However I am wondering how I can limit the results to just 4 days worth of records as I don't want every day since the first record in the database to be displayed. Please can you advise?

Comment: You have to add a WHERE clause inside your query that specifies the interval you want to output. For example, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field < end_4dayperiod AND date_field > start_4dayperiod`